# Excel countif -

Tags: excel, date, countif

Excel countif - I need to count a list of policies that are within a date range (expired policies) and include specific transaction types.

Originally, I needed to do the countif based on excluding values. Now as the transaction types have grown, it would be more efficient to just include the values I want. Below was the formula based on excluding certain values.

=COUNTIFS(A1:A4,"<"&DATE(2018,1,15),B1:B4,"<>"&"Can",B1:B4,"<>"&"END") allows me to exclude values I don't want recorded.

Policies are defined by transaction type: New,Ren,End,Can, REN-1,REN-2 etc...

I only want to count New and Ren within the date formula above however when I edit the above formula to =COUNTIFS(A1:A4,"<"&DATE(2018,1,15),B1:B4,"New",B1:B4,"REN") I just get a 0 value
Thanks for reading

Answer (score 2):

I will go out on a limb and assume your question is "What's wrong with my formula?".

Try:

```
=COUNTIF(C6:C978,"<"&DATE(2018,10,31))
```

Edit: For multiple criteria you must use `COUNTIFS`:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A4,"<"&DATE(2018,1,15),B1:B4,"<>"&"Can",B1:B4,"<>"&"END")
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, cybernetic. I should have provided more information. Col C is dates, Col G is transaction type. so my countif formula has to include both sets of data.=COUNTIF(C6:C978,"<"&DATE(2018,10,31 where (transaction type) G6:G978 = Ren/New only (exclude Can/END)))

Comment: See the edit to my answer. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53400356/edit) to add information instead of relying on comments